# How to set homepage in FIrefox extension using high-level API?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

By using this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.setCharPref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://example.com");
```

I get error about I must use shortcuts, for example:

```
let { Cu } = require('chrome');
```

I tried write like this:

```
let { Cu } = require('chrome');
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.setCharPref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://example.com");
```

No errors. No effect.

Comment: This preference was removed, so now you have to listen to when about:newtab loads and then redirect patch it manually.